# File needs to save three names, it is only saving the last input

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
import os

def createFile():
    employee = open("namesEmployees.txt","a")
    print("The file has been created")
    employee.close()

def addInfo():
    for i in range(3):
        data = input("Type the name of the employee: ")
    employee = open("namesEmployees.txt","w")
    for i in range(3):
        employee.write (data + "\n")
    print("The names have been added")
    employee.close()

def displayInfo():
    employee = open("namesEmployees.txt","r")
    name = employee.read()
    print(name)
    employee.close()


createFile()
addInfo()
displayInfo()
```

When I try to run the code, if I input three different names and then display it, the display only shows the last name three times. What can I do so it saves the three different names properly?

Comment: You are assigning `data = input(...)` three times in a loop. The variable `data` is overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: If you do `data = [input("Type the name of the employee: ") for _ in range(3)]` then `data` will be a list of three inputs, and you can write them all to the file.

Comment: Your createFile function will not necessarily create a file. The variable *data* is overridden during each iteration of the *for* loop in addInfo. You should be using Context Manager patterns when file processing (and in pretty much any other case where the CM is supported). The createFile function is pointless because addInfo will [try to] create a new file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please think carefully about the logic of the code. If we *replace* the value of `data` three times in a row (by using `=`), what do you expect to happen to the first two values? How could they be used later? "What can I do so it saves the three different names properly?" In the studying you had to do to get this far, did you see anything called a "list"? Alternately: what if the user's input got written to the file *before* asking for the next input? Do you see how this would help solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the `addInfo()` function as next:

```
def addInfo():
    employee = open("namesEmployees.txt","w")
    for i in range(3):
        data = input("Type the name of the employee: ") 
        employee.write (data + "\n")
    print("The names have been added")
    employee.close()
```

Comment: @AksenP Did you consider using the more generally accepted Work Manager construct?

Comment: @DarkKnight, if you wish to develop a bicycle from scratch, then do that and ride through. In other words, you haven't read what the question was. The OP hasn't asked to write the whole program from zero for some purpose, that you did. Yes, you can give her\him the suggestions, you can even try to get hired by her\him.

Answer (score -1):

The createFile function is unnecessary because the file is (if possible) created in the addInfo function. You should not repeat things like filenames as literals in multiple functions. Using a constant is better (although 'constant' in Python is merely a convention). Use Context Manager for file handling. Allow for various values for the number of input values required (entries)

```
FILENAME = 'namesEmployees.txt'

def addInfo(entries=3):
    if entries > 0:
        with open(FILENAME, 'w') as output:
            for _ in range(entries):
                data = input('Type the name of the employee: ')
                print(data, file=output)
            print('The names have been added')

def displayInfo():
    with open(FILENAME, 'r') as data:
        print(data.read(), end='')

addInfo()
displayInfo()
```